# Error Bluestacks sidebar_config.json not found

Tags: bluestacks

I have a error!
"Programs\Bluestacks\Engine\UserData\sidebar_config.json file not found"
What to do? Because of this, I can't log in to steam using steam guard!

Answer (score 0):

put this to the file

```
{
    "00": {
        "00": "sidebar_fullscreen",
        "01": "sidebar_volume",
        "02": "sidebar_lock_cursor",
        "03": "sidebar_overlay",
        "04": "sidebar_controls",
        "05": "sidebar_toggle",
        "06": "sidebar_gamepad",
        "07": "sidebar_macro",
        "08": "sidebar_screenshot",
        "09": "sidebar_video_capture",
        "10": "sidebar_media_folder",
        "11": "sidebar_mm",
        "12": "sidebar_location",
        "13": "sidebar_shake",
        "14": "sidebar_rotate"
    }
}
```